# How to make several JQuery elements together

Tags: jquery

Two variables each stands for a jQuery element, how do I make them one variable stands for both elements?
e.g.

```
var a=$("#elem1");
var b=$("#elem2");
```

I tried

```
var c=a+b;
```

to make

```
c=$("#elem1,#elem2");
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I recommend a $-prefix for variables that hold jQuery instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var c = a.add(b);
```

[Here is a **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/Xp5Uj/) to show it working with [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

`var c = $("#elem1, #elem2")` will work.

You can also try this.

```
var a =$("#elem1");
var b =$("#elem1");
var c = a.add(b);
```

Now `c` will contain both `#elem1` and `#elem2`.

`add()` reference - http://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: But why when I try c.animate(...) I get 'Object [object Object][object Object] has no method 'animate''?

Comment: Try this `a.add(b).animate()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a= $("#elem1");
var b= $("#elem2");
var c = a.add(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = $('#elem1, #elem2');
```

Is the correct syntax. See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qrrR/).

Comment: The simplest and thus best solution.

Answer (score -1):

Put both elements under one class.

```
var c = $(".thatclass")
```